# Ansible mysqldb add drop database line

Tags: ansible, mysql-python

Is it possible to add the add-drop database statement in the dump generated by mysql_db ?

My module works fine and the dump is well generated, but i want to add the "-B --add-drop-database" line (like in the mysqldump command)
to get at the beginning of the dump:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `my_db`*/;
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `my_db` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `my_db`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create custom `my.cnf` with

```
[mysqldump]
add-drop-database
```

And pass `my.cnf` path as `config_file` parameter to [mysql_db](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/mysql_db_module.html) module.

Comment: Thx for the response !
Unfortunately, the add-drop-database is still absent in the dump

Answer (score 0):

The ansible `mysql_db` when using `state=dump` is actually running `mysqldump` in the background.

So basically in Ansible you can pass any argument that you can find when running `mysqldump --help` with the option: `dump_extra_args`

So in your case, the playbook can look like:

```
    - name: "Export databases to local file {{dump_prefix}}_*.sql"
      mysql_db:
        name  : "{{ item }}"
        state : dump
        target: "{{dump_prefix}}_{{item}}.sql"
        login_user    : "{{ from_user }}"
        login_password: "..."
        login_host    : "{{ from_server }}"
        dump_extra_args: --column-statistics=0 --add-drop-database
```